# Python reading a file and parsing the required data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi I am reading a file data.txt which is in the below format.

```
Last table change time   : 69 days, 0:17:19 ago
Number of table inserts  : 93
Number of table deletes  : 87
Number of table drops    : 0
Number of table age-outs : 0

Port       Neighbor Device ID             Neighbor Port ID           TTL
Et2/1      CN-Arista2                       Ethernet5/1                120
Et2/2      CN-Arista2                       Ethernet5/2                120
Et2/3      CN-Arista3                       Ethernet5/3                120
Et2/4      CN-Arista                       Ethernet5/4                120
Et64/1     CN-Spine2                      Ethernet64/1               120
Ma1        Arista01.Dmech.rack01             Ethernet1                  120
```

I need out put as follows

```
Et2/1, CN-Arista2, Ethernet5/1
Et2/2, CN-Arista2, Ethernet5/2
Et2/3, CN-Arista3, Ethernet5/3
Et2/4, CN-Arista, Ethernet5/4
Et64/1, CN-Spine2, Ethernet64/1
Ma1, Arista01.Dmech.rack01, Ethernet1
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is that "Last table change time:" bit a part of the file? Or something else?

Comment: And have you considered just opening it with Notepad++ and doing a search-and-replace for ` +` and `, `?

Comment: so, you're skipping the first line, dropping the last field and changing the multiple spaces separating them into a ", "?  anything else? any chance the existing fields gonna get an embedded space?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am skipping first 7 lines, dropping last filed in each column and separating them with a comma

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to do but maybe this gets you in the right direction:

```
filename = 'myfile.txt'

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(*line.split(), sep=', ')
    file.close()
```

Thank you TigerhawkT3 :)

Comment: You can iterate over file objects, by the way: `for line in file: print(*line.split(), sep=', ')`. And you don't need to explicitly close a file if it's opened with a `with` block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
fi = open('data.txt')
fo = open('data.csv')
for line in fi:
     L = line.split()
     S = ' '.join(L[5:8]).replace(',','') +', ' + ', '.join(L[14: : 6]) + '\n'
     fo.write(S)
fo.close()
fi.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input = """Port       Neighbor Device ID             Neighbor Port ID           TTL
Et2/1      CN-Arista2                       Ethernet5/1                120
Et2/2      CN-Arista2                       Ethernet5/2                120
Et2/3      CN-Arista3                       Ethernet5/3                120
Et2/4      CN-Arista                       Ethernet5/4                120
Et64/1     CN-Spine2                      Ethernet64/1               120
Ma1        Arista01.Dmech.rack01             Ethernet1                  120
"""


#create a test file
fn_in = "./testin.txt"
fn_out = "./testout.txt"

with open(fn_in, "w") as fo:
    fo.write(input)

with open(fn_in, "r") as fi, open(fn_out,"w") as fo:

    #drop first line
    for line in fi.readlines()[1:]:
        #split without argument treats consecutive spaces as 1 separator
        #drop last field
        fields = line.split()[:-1]
        fo.write(", ".join(fields)+"\n")
```

did it work?

```
$ cat testout.txt


Et2/1, CN-Arista2, Ethernet5/1
Et2/2, CN-Arista2, Ethernet5/2
Et2/3, CN-Arista3, Ethernet5/3
Et2/4, CN-Arista, Ethernet5/4
Et64/1, CN-Spine2, Ethernet64/1
Ma1, Arista01.Dmech.rack01, Ethernet1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. Below is the final code that works well per my requirement.

```
fn_in = "data.txt"
with open(fn_in, "r") as fi:
    #drop first 7 lines
    for line in fi.readlines()[7:]:
        #split without argument treats consecutive spaces as 1 separator
        #drop last field
        fields = line.split()[:-1]
        if fields:
            print(", ".join(fields))
```

Comment: cool. txs for accept.  1 thing - I believe in answering the problem at hand and not speculate.  but, as is, the drop 7 and the actual field handling, is highly dependent on your current input format.  You could make it a bit more robust by:  a)  looking for the `Port       Neighbor Device ID` line with something like `line.lower().replace(" ", "").startwith("portneighbordeviceid"`) and then processing.  b) on the next, actual, lines, check that you have the expected # of fields (4) with a len(split(line)) ==4.  c) don't hesitate to `raise RuntimeError("bad format:%s" % (line)`

Comment: your call, but 20 minutes writing a sanity check may save you hours down the line.

Comment: @JLPeyret Sorry for the late response, that's a great suggestion. I will try that. 
Thank you.